# What is the motivation for finding this solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, contest-math, real-numbers

I was looking at Putnam problem A1 from 1995:

> Let S be a set of real numbers which is closed under
>   multiplication (that is, if a and b are in S, then so is ab).
>   Let T and U be disjoint subsets of S whose union is
>   S. Given that the product of any three (not necessarily
>   distinct) elements of T is in T and that the product of
>   any three elements of U is in U, show that at least one of the two subsets T,U is closed under multiplication.

I had tried a few different things, but I couldn't solve it and I looked up the solution:

> Suppose on the contrary that there exist $t_1$, $t_2$ ∈ T
>   with $t_1t_2$ ∈ U and $u_1,u_2$ ∈ U with $u_1u_2$ ∈ T. Then
>   $(t_1t_2)u_1u_2$ ∈ U while $t_1t_2(u_1u_2)$ ∈ T, contradiction.

My question is, what train of thought should I have been following to find this (or another) solution? I of course realized myself that if if $t_1 t_2 \not \in T,$ then  $t_1 t_2 \in U$. But I never thought to take elements from both sets simultaneously and multiply all four elements at the same time. Even if I ha thought of randomly multiplying all four terms, I'm not sure I would've realized the contradiction until I stared at it for a while (I didn't even think it was a good idea to try to prove this one by contradiction).

Comment: To do a proof by contradiction, you would have to use both $t_1t_2$ and $u_1u_2$.  Multiplying seems reasonable.

Comment: Many good proofs are far more obvious in retrospect than while searching for them. However the crossover nature of the forbidden situation here (neither $T$ nor $U$ closed) did give a good indication of where to start.

Comment: @Joffan Thanks for the input. Unfortunately, I was totally focused on a "constructive" proof for some reason. As I mentioned in my comment to Eric Wofsey, I was trying to think of different examples of $S, U, T$ and find something which all the subsets (U or T) which are closed under multiplication share. For example, I knew that if S contained any number greater than $1$, then $S$ (and the one subset guaranteed to be closed under multiplication) had to be unbounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, contradiction is a very natural approach to take here because you are trying to prove a disjunction.  One of the most common ways to prove "$P$ or $Q$" (without proving $P$ or proving $Q$ individually) is to assume that both fail and get a contradiction.  The reason this is a good strategy is that you can't really hope to prove $P$ or $Q$ directly (how could you, since you can't prove either one of the statements individually?).  On the other hand, the assumption that both fail is something that is often easy to use.

Now when doing a proof by contradiction, you start by taking elements from both sets simultaneously, since what you are trying to prove is that *either* $T$ or $U$ is closed under multiplication.  The negation of this is that neither $T$ nor $U$ is closed under multiplication, so to get a contradiction you would assume you have a counterexample to both.  This gives you the elements $t_1,t_2,u_1$, and $u_2$ as in the solution.  There's not really anything you can do with these elements other than multiply them in some way, and so it's natural enough to consider $t_1t_2u_1u_2$.  Also, note that you haven't yet used the assumption that $T$ and $U$ are disjoint, so it is natural to try to find some element that is forced to be in both $T$ and $U$.  And in order to do so, the obvious thing to try to use is that $T$ and $U$ are closed under triple products.  And given $t_1,t_2,u_1$, and $u_2$, the only three elements you know of in $T$ are $t_1,t_2$, and $u_1u_2$, and similarly for $U$.

Ultimately, I doubt there's any deep secret that makes this solution obvious: this is a Putnam problem, and it's meant to force you to be clever.  But I hope I've explained why the steps of the solution are reasonably natural things to try.

Comment: Thank you very much for the walkthrough, it is immensly helpful. For some reason I thought that the "not neccesarily distinct" part was going to come into our proof.

Comment: As for "how could you prove P or Q directly", I was trying to think of examples of $S, U, T$ and find what they all had in common, hoping to find some restrictions on the sets. For example, I knew that if S included any number greater than $1$, then S had to be unbounded on at least one side. Of course I found more examples of S such as the naturals, the integers, the rationals, etc.

Comment: @EricWofsey: In your second paragraph, you should delete your first "either". "Either $T$ or $U$ is closed" is not the same as "$T$ or $U$ is closed".